# Saving Excel macro with Parameters in Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am trying to pass file names as arguments to a macro using Automation Anywhere. For that I'm trying to save my

```
Sub openfile(Byval filePath as String) 
Dim WB as workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

End Sub
```

After saving n closing. When opening the macros I'm unable to find the openfile in my list of macros.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you saving the excel file, that contains the macro as `.xlsm`?

Comment: Procedures that take arguments do not appear in the macros list.

Comment: The only ones that show up in that list are the ones that have no arguments. If they require arguments, you have to run them thru code.

Comment: Hi @braX can you let me know how to run it through code, im new to macros

Comment: @SivaVelugubantla you need to write another sub (without parameters) that calls it like `openfile "C:\temp\example.xlsx"`